# Google Play Games Get Username

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-games

I have been struggling to find up-to-date, kotlin documentation for Google Play Games services in my app. I managed to (after lots of coffee) get a sign in popup for the user, along with leaderboad and achievement functionality, and this all works great! However I'm adding a new profile/stats system in my next update and think it would be cool for it to display the users display-name in this stats menu.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea on how to get the userName, if signed the user is signed it, in kotlin? Code samples are much appreciated however links to documentation is useful as well!

Many thanks,
Joshu